# Prevent holding keyboard pressed in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, keypress

I need the user to insert text into a textarea as one letter per keypress, so if a key is held down it will write just one letter ('a') instead of multiple letters ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'). To enter this last string the user must press-release the keyboard button multiple times.

Is this possible?

Javascript and JQuery can be used.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: @ASDFGerte: Oh, I bet it is.

Comment: I'm curious: **Why** do you need to disable this standard functionality?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the input method of continues press is likely handled on driver level or even more difficult parts, i doubt you can access those from javascript? E.g. some gamer keyboards allow for different setups on the driver and only forward the single presses, how would one possibly overwrite this?

Comment: @ASDFGerte: If we're getting into customized keyboards that lie to the OS, sure, that's going to be a problem. But in the normal course of things, browsers supply discrete events for `keydown`, `keyup`, and `keypress`. I've added an answer below (but still don't think doing this is a good idea :-) ).

Comment: I just need it for a sort of clicker game where the user is also asked to type. I know, normally it's an awful idea, this is just a very particular game :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Caveat:** I would strongly suggest not doing this, not least because of the potential unintended consequences for users using assistive technology.

You could watch `keypress` and `keyup` and disallow further `keypress` events until you've seen a `keyup`. Note that this won't prevent their holding down a key and toggling some *other* key (like <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), but it does require them to toggle *some* key:

```js
var preventKeypress = false;
$("textarea")
  .on("keyup", function() {
    // Allow keypresses again
    preventKeypress = false;
  })
  .on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (preventKeypress) {
      // Disallow it
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      // Allow it, but then disallow until we next see keyup
      preventKeypress = true;
    }
  });
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not saying it's foolproof, or a good idea... :-)

Comment: Thanks, very smart solution! I also won't suggest doing this, but this is just for a strange browser game. Thanks again!